# Electrons background.js when behind Proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, background, electron

I'm working on an Electron app which has to work behind a proxy server with simple auth.
Content in the mainWindow can communicate through the proxy by using the "app.on('login')" way.
I also have connetions established by the background.js file which fail when behind the proxy.
Is there a way to make connections in background.js also work with the proxy configuration?

Thanks!

background.js

```
app.on('login', function (event, webContents, request, authInfo, callback) {
    // Es existiert ein Proxy, wir benötigen Zugangsdaten!
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('proxy erkannt');

    // Es ist ein Proxy Zugang erforderlich
    proxy = true;

    // Funktionieren die bekannten Daten?
    callback('proxytest', 'test');
})
```

The mainWindow can connect to the server while connctions from background.js can't.

Comment: What is the app.on('login') way? When does the connection to the proxy work? What did you already try? Do you have some code examples?

Comment: app.on('login') triggers when the browserwindow is presented simple auth by a proxy. but this only works for the browserwindow, not the background.js. 
Connections established in the background.js and not in the browserwindow are not working at all. I think electron copies the proxy settings for the system to connect the browserwindow while code in background.js can't connect at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use ipcmain and ipcrenderer for communication between server and window. So you can trigger any event for communicating.